# object mapping when using Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongo-db and i have few questions.

I have the following code:

```
public class User
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Order> orders;
}
public class Order
{
    private String id;
    private String orderName;
    private Date orderDate;
}
```

What's the best persisting strategy for User object ? 
should i create collection for both User and Order or just for User ?
should i save Order and then user ?

i am using spring data MongoRepository

Thank you.

Comment: There's good information on the mongo site about this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-decisions

Answer (score 0):

I would consider how you're accessing the data when modeling. Some questions to ask yourself:

1. Do I need to get a user with his orders in one call?
2. How many orders are with a user on average? If it's a lot, maybe not best to denormalize user and orders.
3. How will my front end access this information? Will most calls to user even need orders? Will that information be too heavy/slow on the wire?

In general I would err on the side of denormalizing instead of the relational instinct to normalize. It's ok to have redundant data and to have inconsistent data.

Mongo doesn't do joins real time - at best you can do map/reduce.

The joining of data therefore either needs to be in the database (denormalized) or in the UI.